Connecting all points with lines in 3D plots in R
I am trying to make a 3D plot where all pairs of points would be connected by a line. The closer I can get is what follows (i.e., using type = "b"), but that only plots the "path", it's not connecting all pairs of points. Is there any way to do this in R?
library(tidyverse)
library(plot3D)

data.frame(dim1 = rnorm(n = 20), dim2 = rnorm(n = 20), dim3 = rnorm(n = 20) ) %>%
    scatter3D(
        x = .$dim1,
        y = .$dim2,
        z = .$dim3,
        type = "b",
        pch = 20,
        xlab = "Dimension 1",
        ylab = "Dimension 2",
        zlab = "Dimension 3",
        phi = 40,
        bty = "b",
        cex = 2
        )



One solution is to add multiple calls to lines3D, supplying all pairs of data points:
for(i in 1:(nrow(data) - 2)) {
  for(j in (i + 2):nrow(data)) {
    slice(data, c(i,j)) %>% 
      lines3D(x=.$dim1, y=.$dim2, z=.$dim3, add=TRUE, colkey = FALSE)
  }
}


